# how can I get two parameters values from Query string using jquery?

Tags: javascript

Query string :

```
Pages/Service.aspx?id=4&comment=1
```

I am new to jquery ,Kindly help me out with a simple solution to get the Id and COMMENT in "var id & var comment" using jQUERY in asp.net C#

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with parsing strings?

Answer (score 2):

Use following code

```
<script>
    function getQuery(key){
        var temp = location.search.match(new RegExp(key + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"));
        if(!temp) return.
        return temp[1];
    }

    var id = getQuery('id');
    var comment = getQuery('comment');

</script>
```