# jQuery : How to get value from URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have URL like :

```
http://domain/catergory/Education?max-post=5/
```

How can I get `Education` from that URL. Education is in between `"/"` and `"?"`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use regular expressions or the `split` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regexp for it:

```
var url = 'http://domain/catergory/Education?max-post=5/';

var val = url.match(/\/([^\/\?]*)\?/)[1];
```

To understand the regexp you can use this site: http://regex101.com/r/aQ3yF1#javascript

Comment: I got the hint, hope that link is more helpful. (And yes, i do find writing regexp to be much easier than reading regexps wrote by others.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), it splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

```
var url = "http://domain/catergory/Education?max-post=5/";
var arr = url.split("?")[0].split("/");
var edu = arr[arr.length - 1]
console.log(edu);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DQMtM/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getQuery(key) {
    var queryStr = location.search.match(new RegExp(key + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"));
    if (!queryStr)
        return

    return queryStr[1];
}

var id = getQuery('id');
var comment = getQuery('comment');
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366195/how-can-i-get-two-parameters-values-from-query-string-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
value = url.replace('http://domain/catergory/','');
value = value.substring(0, s.indexOf('?'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://domain/catergory/Education?max-post=5/";
var arr = url.split("?")[0].split("y/");
var edu = arr[1]
console.log(edu);
```